# Fastest way to send struct containing pointer through TCP socket

Tags: c++, sockets

Please keep in mind that I'm trying to build sub-millisecond level latency sensitive server.

Therefore, I want to keep the process as minimal as possible. Such as minimizing memcpy call.

Here's the thing.

Let's say, I have a following struct:

```
struct data {
  int sequence;
  ...
  size_t len;
  void* buf;
}
```

Simplest way to send above struct will be:

```
send(fd, &data.sequence, sizeof(int));
...
send(fd, &data.len, sizeof(size_t));
send(fd, data.buf, data.len);
```

There is nothing wrong with that on most of the situation.

But when repeatedly executed, I've noticed that such code generates huge amount of overhead.
(Like, when executed on every 2~3ms).

Programs slows down as more `send` calls are made.

As far as I've tested, below code worked dramatically faster.

```
size_t sendBufLen = sizeof(int) + ... + sizeof(size_t) + data.len;
void* sendBuf = malloc(sendBufLen);
int sendBufIndex = 0;

memcpy(sendBuf, &data.sequence, sizeof(int));
sendBufIndex += sizeof(int);
...
memcpy(sendBuf + sendBufIndex, &data.len, sizeof(size_t));
sendBufIndex += sizeof(size_t);
memcpy(sendBuf + sendBufIndex, data.buf, data.len);

//finally send
send(fd, sendBuf, sendBufLen);
free(sendBuf);
```

So my question is,

Is the code below actually intended to work faster in my situation?

If not, what could be the flaws that made misleading result?

Is there any better way to do buffering before making send call?

Comment: Do you know how to use `writev`?

Comment: How did you configured a socket? It may turn out your call of `send` blocks until data are received creating this overhead.

Comment: Thank you for answering dumb question. Seems like making send call non-blocking and using writev could be the solution.

Comment: Or, look at `sendmsg` which has an `iovec` just like `writev`

Comment: Making it non-blocing wont' help in the slightest. `send()` blocks until the data has been buffered locally, rather than until it has been received by the peer, and making it non-blocking will only cause it to return an error when the local send buffer is full, rather than magically speeding up the whole process. @MarekR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have struct like this

```
struct data {
  int sequence;
  ...
  size_t len;
  void* buf;
};

data my_data;
```

you can send it like this:

```
send(fd, &my_data, sizeof(my_data) - sizeof(void*));
send(fd, my_data.buf, my_data.len);
```

This code looks unclear and will break if someone change fields order. But, probably, it's faster, than alternatives.

Also make sure you really know fields location and size. Better to wrap your struct by `#pragma pack(push, 1)`, like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct data {
  int sequence;
  ...
  size_t len;
  void* buf;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: `writev()` and `sendmsg(0` will be faster that this. One system call instead of two.